Interpretation of Diffusion Coefficient in Photon Diffusion Equation
The diffusion coefficient in photon diffusion, as explained/defined here: Factor of 3 in Photon Diffusion coefficient
seems counterintuitive because diffusion is inversely proportional to the scattering coefficient. (Why would diffusion decrease if scattering of photons increases?)
